# How to make sure that the randomized coordinates will not fall into specific coordinates in a 2D array? The language is C

Tags: arrays, c, coordinates, pacman, randomized-algorithm

I am creating a game in C, and I want to randomly place blocks and foods inside a 2d array. I have randomized the x and y coordinates of the blocks and the food into 1d arrays, i.e. foodCol[] and foodRow[]; blockCol[] and blockRow[]. However, there comes a possibility that the blocks and foods would fall into the same coordinates. I also want them not to to be placed on the coordinate (1, 1) and beside each other, except diagonally. I came up with this code, but it does not work and maybe there are other intuitive approach.

Here is the code:

```
for (foodCount = 0; foodCount < randDim; foodCount++){
        for (foodCount2 = 0; foodCount2 < randDim; foodCount2++){
            while ((foodCol[foodCount] == blockCol[foodCount2] && foodRow[foodCount] == blockRow[foodCount2]) ||
                    (foodCol[foodCount] == blockCol[foodCount2]+1 && foodRow[foodCount] == blockRow[foodCount2]) ||
                    (foodCol[foodCount] == blockCol[foodCount2]-1 && foodRow[foodCount] == blockRow[foodCount2]) ||
                    (foodCol[foodCount] == blockCol[foodCount2] && foodRow[foodCount] == blockRow[foodCount2]+1) ||
                    (foodCol[foodCount] == blockCol[foodCount2] && foodRow[foodCount] == blockRow[foodCount2]-1) ||
                    (foodRow[foodCount] == 1 && foodCol[foodCount] == 1) || 
                    (foodRow[foodCount] == 2 && foodCol[foodCount] == 1) || 
                    (foodRow[foodCount] == 1 && foodCol[foodCount] == 2) || 
                    (foodRow[foodCount] == 2 && foodCol[foodCount] == 2)){
                foodNum2 = (rand()%9)+1;
                shuffle(&foodCol[foodCount2], &foodCol[foodNum2]);
                shuffle(&foodRow[foodCount2], &foodRow[foodNum2]);
            }
        }
    }
```

Remarks: the shuffle function is just a basic function of shuffling 1d arrays. Also, the foodcount and randdim are irrelevant to my problem.

Thanks!

Comment: I think you could create a single 1D array of coordinates, shuffle that, then iterate over it, checking your rules and placing food/blocks where allowed by the counts and neighbors.

Comment: Never describe a problem merely as “it does not work.” Always show sample input that reproduces the problem, show the observed output, show the desired output, and, if it is not obvious, explain the difference between the observed output and the desired output. Edit the question to provide a [mre]. It is insufficient to describe “the shuffle function is just a basic function of shuffling 1d arrays”; you should show the code.

Comment: To make the problem reproducible, you can temporarily replace the `rand` and `srand`  functions with `int rand(void) { next = next * 1103515245 + 12345; return (unsigned int)(next/65536) % 32768; }` and `void srand(unsigned int seed) { next = seed; }` and use a fixed seed.

Comment: That said, it is unclear what approach you are trying to take with this code. If the `shuffle` function is just a swap of two items, then the `shuffle` calls shown just change where a particular food instances is within the lists of coordinates in `foodCol` and `foodRow`; it does not change the location of the food within the two-dimensional grid. E.g., if food 3 is next to a block, and you swap food 3 with food 9, then you have food 9 next to a block. You have just changed which food has the problem, not solved the problem.